# How to create article's link in a nav bar with EE 2?

Tags: php, expressionengine

I’m looking for create automatically a link in a nav bar of the page on an article by the

wiki, unsuccessfully, I would like some help about it, I know I have to usecategory

(I think but I’m not sure…) because I have some difficulties in understanding the

utility, and especially how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Path Variables](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/wiki/wiki_templates_page.html#path-variables) as part of the [Wiki Module](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/wiki/) in ExpressionEngine, you can link to an individual Wiki article/page by using the following code:

`<a href="{path:view_article}">{title}</a>`

This would output the following example HTML code:

`<a href="http://example.com/index.php/wiki/Test_Page">Test Page</a>`

You can see this tag in use throughout the Wiki Theme Templates in `/themes/wiki_themes/`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, rjb; Now that I found where I can change my theme, I understand a little better how to do thanks to your answer, I see that I have a lot of work to can understand how it works and to be able to properly implement it, I also see that other problems will arise so, if it is possible for you, I would like you not stay away, just in case^^^^ Thank you so much rjb, Best wishes.
seb